# JPopupMenu change size dynamically if there is a JPanel inside

Tags: java, swing, jpopupmenu, preferredsize, sizing

I have a `JPopupMenu` and I want to change it's inner size dynamically depending on it's `inner components' size`. In my SSCCE I described the problem.

**SSCCE:**

```
public class PopupTest2 {
    public static void main(String[] a) {
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(500, 500);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        final JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.RED));

        final JPopupMenu menu = new JPopupMenu();

        // critical step
        JPanel itemPanel = new JPanel();
        itemPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(itemPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

        final JMenuItem[] items = new JMenuItem[10];
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            JMenuItem item = new JMenuItem("Item #"+String.valueOf(i));
            itemPanel.add(item);
            items[i] = item;
        }

        menu.add(itemPanel);

        JToggleButton button = new JToggleButton("Press me");
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            boolean pressed = false;
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                pressed = !pressed;
                if (pressed) {
                    for (JMenuItem item : items) {
                        item.setText(item.getText()+" changed");
                    }
                } else {
                    for (JMenuItem item : items) {
                        item.setText(item.getText().substring(0, item.getText().length() - 8));
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        panel.add(button, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        panel.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                if (e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON3) {
                    menu.show(panel, (int) (e.getX() - menu.getPreferredSize().getWidth()), e.getY());
                }
            }
        });
        frame.setContentPane(panel);
        frame.setUndecorated(true);
        frame.setBackground(new Color(50, 50, 50, 200));

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Steps 2 reproduce:**

1. Right-click to show popup menu.
2. Click the `Press me` button (on the top of window).
3. Right-click to show popup menu again (bug #1 - popup is still small-size)
4. Right-click to show popup menu again (popup menu size is OK)
5. Click the `Press me` button again.
6. Right-click to show popup menu. (bug #2 - popup is still large-size)

How can I force `JPopupMenu` to change its size before showing? And why does it work if I add items directly to `popupMenu`?

Comment: Not an SSCCE. What class is `MyUI` ?

Comment: don't use setUI, instead register your custom ui with the uiManager and let it handle the setting automatically

Comment: _// YES, I NEED THAT PANEL, IT IS NOT BUG, I REALLY NEED THAT_ why?

Comment: @kleopatra I need `JPanel` because I have a complicated content inside `JPopupMenu`.

Comment: don't want to be rude, but please leave to **ME** what/if/when I answer/comment. In about 99% of problems due to unusual setups it's the mis-perceived need for the unusual that's the real problem ;-)

Comment: you are aware that the sizing is not the worst (IMO) of the problems introduced by the panel? To see what I mean: move the mouse over a menuItem and see the popup hiding ... The base problem is that menuItems et al build a complex ecosystem that tends to blow if used elsewhere

Comment: I know about that problem, but, as it has no relation to the current question, I did not post an extra code which resolve it. @kleopatra will you try to help me **with my question** or not?

Comment: _as it has no relation to the current question_ haha ... and you base that evaluation on .. what? Sorry, it's the exact same reason (most probably): you are doing thingies in a fundamentally unusual (to put it mildly, looks wrong to me) way. My advice is to take a step back and describe your requirements (vs. the problems you have with a perceived solution)

Comment: *fundamentally unusual* and what? If I need turn-screw, I'll create it, but I would not use hammer. Swing API allows to change its default components according to dev' requirements. The problem is, I don't know all of the current component niceties, that's why this question is here.

Comment: still don't understand, whats issue there to create, build, modify, remove, add Items in JPopup before is visible (see API), or call pack() to the already visible JPopup Items, there isn't some diff to JFrame, JDialog, sure you'd need to check used LayoutManager for JPopup, hmmmm please is there another issue, because JPopup, or BasicsXxxPopup is there mentioned a few times with excelent code workarounds

Comment: @mKorbel I've solved the problem with myself. The problem was in `layout` used in `JPanel` (between `Popup` and `items`). It works excellent now. `pack()` would not solve that.

Comment: cool, how about sharing the solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks all, but I've found the solution after continuous debugging. The problem was in `layout` used in `JPanel` (between Popup and items). It called the `getPreferredSize()` of `JPanel` which called directly `menuItem.getPrefferedSize()`, which called `BasicMenuItemUI.getPrefferedSize()`. The last method uses the `MainMenuLayoutHelper` class to get the preferred size. This class stores the data about size in `Properties` static object.

The default `JPopupMenu` layout - `DefaultMenuLayout` - clears this static data each time its `preferredLayoutSize()` method called, with call `MenuItemLayoutHelper.clearUsedClientProperties(popupMenu)`. We will do the same - call this method with our `JPanel` parameter with further `revalidate()` call:

```
public class PopupTest2 {
    public static void main(String[] a) {
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(500, 500);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        final JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

        final JPopupMenu menu = new JPopupMenu();

        final JPanel itemPanel = new JPanel();
        itemPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(itemPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

        final JMenuItem[] items = new JMenuItem[1];
        for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
            JMenuItem item = new JMenuItem("Item #"+String.valueOf(i));
            itemPanel.add(item);
            items[i] = item;
        }
        menu.updateUI();

        menu.add(itemPanel);

        JToggleButton button = new JToggleButton("Press me");
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            boolean pressed = false;
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                pressed = !pressed;
                if (pressed) {
                    for (JMenuItem item : items) {
                        item.setText(item.getText()+" changed");
                    }
                } else {
                    for (JMenuItem item : items) {
                        item.setText(item.getText().substring(0, item.getText().length() - 8));
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        panel.add(button, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        panel.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                if (e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON3) {
                    MenuItemLayoutHelper.clearUsedClientProperties(itemPanel);
                    itemPanel.revalidate();
                    menu.show(panel, (int) (e.getX() - menu.getPreferredSize().getWidth()), e.getY());
                }
            }
        });
        frame.setContentPane(panel);
        frame.setUndecorated(true);
        frame.setBackground(new Color(50, 50, 50, 200));

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**PS:** Dear reader, it is not the best way to write your code. I do that because I **really** need that (I have such requirements). If you can build your `JPopupMenu` without `JPanel` inside, do not use code in this answer, please.

Answer (score 4):

Here is one way to do this:

```
public static void main(String[] a) {
    final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setSize(500, 500);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    final JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.RED));

    final JPopupMenu menu = new JPopupMenu();

    // critical step
    final JPanel itemPanel = new JPanel();
    itemPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(itemPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

    final JMenuItem[] items = new JMenuItem[10];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        JMenuItem item = new JMenuItem("Item #"+String.valueOf(i));
        itemPanel.add(item);
        items[i] = item;
    }

    menu.add(itemPanel);

    JToggleButton button = new JToggleButton("Press me");
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        boolean pressed = false;
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            pressed = !pressed;
            if (pressed) {
                for (JMenuItem item : items) {
                    item.setText(item.getText()+" changed");
                    item.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(70, 50));
                    item.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(70, 50));
                    item.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(70, 50));
                    itemPanel.invalidate();
                }
            } else {
                for (JMenuItem item : items) {
                    item.setText(item.getText().substring(0, item.getText().length() - 8));
                    item.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(130, 50));
                    item.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(130, 50));
                    item.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(130, 50));
                    itemPanel.invalidate();
                }
            }
        }
    });

    panel.add(button, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    panel.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            if (e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON3) {
                menu.show(panel, (int) (e.getX() - menu.getPreferredSize().getWidth()), e.getY());
            }
        }
    });
    frame.setContentPane(panel);
    frame.setUndecorated(true);
    frame.setBackground(new Color(50, 50, 50, 200));

    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you attempt, but what should I do if don't know the size of each item?

Comment: `but what should I do if don't know the size of each item` == cal pack(), SwingUtilities returns ancesor, parent, window for conponent only have to decide, which one is proper for this job

Comment: @mKorbel please see the answer of mine and you'll understand why that should not work.

Answer (score -2):

You have to add

```
menu.updateUI();
```

after add menu items.

```
    final JMenuItem[] items = new JMenuItem[10];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        JMenuItem item = new JMenuItem("Item #"+String.valueOf(i));
        itemPanel.add(item);
        item.setUI(new MyUI());
        items[i] = item;
    }
    menu.updateUI(); <<<<<<--------

    menu.add(itemPanel);
```

Comment: @nashuald And how should that help?

Comment: When you add or remove components on JComponent class, it is necessary to update UI. The API does not explain much about how it works internally. In this [post](https://forums.oracle.com/thread/1350516#jive-7913418063723235912154) DarrylBurke explains it a little more.

Comment: *> it is necessary to update UI* ok. right. but use the `updateUI` method for that is too prodigally.

Comment: By example, when you have to edit JTree node, and text is largest than its original value, node looks truncated. Then you have to update the node renderer in order to resize the node.

Comment: no, you never use updateUI in application code: if you think you need it for a tree, then something is wrong with your model - most probably changing the underlying data structure under the feet of the model

Comment: @kleopatra strange but I'm agree with you =D